# PHP appending GET vars to SESSION

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I wanted to make a simple shopping cart which takes a $_GET variable and puts it in the $_SESSION variable. The code I have tried is this:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (is_numeric($_GET['add'])) $_SESSION[(string)$_GET['add']] = 1; ?>
```

Because my item ids are numeric so I check first to stop random things to be added to the session variable. I then then do a var_dump to see the result. The first time I run the code with ?add=102 I get:

```
array(1) { [102]=> int(1) }
```

I then run the script again with ?add=108 I get:

```
array(1) { [108]=> int(1) }
```

What I want is:

```
array(2) { ["102"]=> int(1), ["108"]=> int(1) }
```

What am I doing wrong? My concept is to convert the $_GET variable to a string and store the quantity 1 and the string value of $_GET in $_SESSION associatively. This should allow me to add as many items as long as their id is not the same, which is what I want.

Here is alternatives I have tried:

```
strval($_GET['add']), 
(string)($_GET['add']), 
$_GET['add']
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this $_SESSION[(string)$_GET['add'][]] = 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `$_SESSION` keys that are numeric.
Create another array in the session, e.g. `$_SESSION['items']`

Then:

```
session_start();
if(is_numeric($_GET['add']))
{
    $_SESSION['items'][(string)$_GET['add']] = 1;
}
```

It's much easier to iterate over this items array later, when you have other information in your session.

Comment: This answer works for me. However, I would still like to hear an explanation for RiggsFolly's answers. Are there any pros/cons compared to this one?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an amalgamation of Satya's comment and mthie's answer but the complete answer should I think be

1. You would be well advised to encapsulate the array you are building in its own named location
   and
2. you need to `add to` the array each time rather than `overwrite` it

so try

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(is_numeric($_GET['add'])) {
       $_SESSION['add'][][(string)$_GET['add']] = 1;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the "[ ]" in the session variable. Will that be a three dimensional array?

Comment: It will make $_SESSION[$_GET['add']] into an array, as you said you wanted in your question. If you are unsure what it will actually look like add a print_r( $_SESSION[(string)$_GET['add']]) to the code.